# Filter entries by month regardless of year using custom Date/Time and paginate them

Tags: entries, pagination, filter

I am looking to filter entries by a given month regardless of year. The filter would be based on a custom Date/Time input.  My last goal would allow them to be paginated.

```
{% set firstDayOfMonth = year ~ "-" ~ month ~ "-01" %}
{% set daysInThisMonth = firstDayOfMonth|date('t') %}
{% set lastDayOfMonth  = year ~ "-" ~ month ~ "-" ~ daysInThisMonth %}

{% set thisMonthsEntries = craft.entries.section('messages').messageDate('and', '>= ' ~ firstDayOfMonth, '<= ' ~ lastDayOfMonth) %}

{% paginate thisMonthsEntries as entriesOnPage %}
    {% for entry in entriesOnPage %}
        {# ... whatever your code does... #}
    {% endfor %}
{% endpaginate %}
```

This is my original code. My first guess is I would need to have an array of years and loop through each year applying to the above code, however I am unclear on how to get a unique list of years that my entries are related too. Then I would probably have multiple sets of entries which would then need to be merged some how for output.

Answer (score 1):

I think you are right and there's no chance to do what you want with parameters on a single ElementCriteriaModel.

You could definitely do it with many queries, the first one to get your years array, then one for each year. Merging them is simple with Twig's [`merge`](http://twig.sensiolabs.org/doc/filters/merge.html) filter. But then you'd end up with a manually composed array of entry models and don't have the convenience of a single ElementCriteriaModel. Methods like [`getNext()`](http://buildwithcraft.com/docs/templating/entrymodel#getNext) or – important in your case – the [`{% paginate %}`](http://buildwithcraft.com/docs/templating/paginate) tag won't work with an array of entry models!

Let's skip the paginate problem for now and look at that query flood, you'd produce. Sure, Craft has the [`{% cache %}`](http://buildwithcraft.com/docs/templating/cache) tag, but if your entries are modified regularly, there'll always be people who access the uncached version.

But what about another solution, why not do a single query to get all your "messages" entries and filter them in your template with a simple conditional:

```
{# Get all `messages` entries #}
{% set entries = craft.entries.section('messages') %}

{# Loop through all entries with a `messageDate` month of `myMonth` regardless the year #}
{% for entry in entries if entry.messageDate|date('m') == myMonth %}
    {{ entry.title }}
{% endfor %}
```

You'd still have no solution yet for your pagination problem, but this should be way less expensive on performance, and it's really easy to implement.

Comment: I will need pagination due to the amount of entries that will be on the page.  Which makes me think, if there is a lot of overhead to filter the way I need, my UX for filtering might need to change. I may need to have the client offer a drop-down for year as well as month.

Comment: You mean you're backpedaling to `.messageDate('and', '>= ' ~ firstDayOfMonth, '<= ' ~ lastDayOfMonth)`?

Comment: Using a single ElementCriteriaModel is probably your best bet to get pagination implemented. All other methods would require a custom replication..